# Google API PHP Client library for Youtube is NOT connecting to Youtube

Tags: php, api, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have been trying to work in youtube php client library but was unable to connect it.

I have read and tried the google documentation (google developers) and github repository documentation (https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client#installation) for its installation using composer or cloning directly using git.

But whenever I tried to surf the webpage, it always show a blank page. I tried to debug it; in which I came to know that the at the **require_once 'vendor/autoload.php'** line, it is stucking.

**My directory structure is:**

/var/www/html/test/index.php (My logical code)

/var/www/html/test/google-php-api-client (Php client API folder)

**Try 1: Downloaded Directly from RELEASE (google-php-api-client-2.0.2) or by using Composer -- NOT WORKING**

```
require_once 'google-api-php-client/vendor/autoload.php';   
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Client_Library_Examples");
$client->setDeveloperKey("MY_API_KEY");
$service = new Google_Service_Books($client);
$optParams = array('filter' => 'free-ebooks');
$results = $service->volumes->listVolumes('Henry David Thoreau', $optParams);
foreach ($results as $item) {
  echo $item['volumeInfo']['title'], "<br /> \n";
}
```

**Try 2: Cloning from GitHub (git clone -b v1-master https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client.git
    ) -- NOT WORKING**

Please, help. Thanks

```
set_include_path('google-api-php-client/src');
require_once 'Google/Client.php';
require_once 'Google/Service/YouTube.php';
```

In this try, the code is not executing after this line **require_once 'Google/Service/YouTube.php';**

Please, help.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu.

Comment: Try 1 is google books not YouTube, try 2 doesn't do anything besides add the header files so wouldn't show anything would it.

Comment: In Try 2, the code stop executing at this line: require_once 'Google/Service/YouTube.php'; and doesn't showing any error.